# Efficient formula binding at runtime

Tags: java, runtime, formula, jvm-languages

One of the elements of my UI is a table showing a list of items, aggregated by category, with some formulae (see target output below).

What would be the *best* approach to allow the user to bind cells to spreadsheet-like formulae?

- performance: the actual data changes frequently, the tables can be big and the formulae complex, so performance and CPU usage are a concern.
- ease of configuration (assuming configuration is done by a developer so it can involve programming)
- maintainability of configuration

The approaches I have envisaged so far:

1. use the Java Scripting API but I'd rather stick to a JVM based approach for better performance
2. create an `interface Formula { double calculate(); }` and generate, compile and load implementations at runtime - that allows the JIT to compile the generated methods
3. same as 2 but using another JVM based language, such as clojure, which allows easy on-the-fly compiling and has a well-suited functional approach (map/reduce would help for the average and sum calculations below for example) - not sure about the performance implications though.

**Which approach would make more sense? Are there any other solutions or libraries that I should consider?**

---

**Example**

To make the goal clearer, here is a contrived example - let's assume the items in the table are:

```
public class Item() {
    public String category;
    public String name;
    public int quantity;
    public double price;
}
```

**Target Output**

```
Category     Name        Quantity    Price (avg)     Value (sum)
All                                      82            1,090

Bikes                                    45              650
             Bike 1         10           40              400
             Bike 2          5           50              250

Cars                                    120              440
             Car 1           3          100              300
             Car 2           1          140              140
```

**Columns configuration**

The columns could be defined like this:

```
Column #      Formula
    1         item.name;
    2         item.quantity;
    3         item.price;
    4         Math.abs(column_2 * column_3); //calls a JDK method
```

**Aggregation configuration**

And the aggregation categories and summary formulae could be defined like this:

```
AGGREGATION #1: Category cat = item.category();
Column #      Formula
    1         cat;
    2         "";
    3         thisColumn.filter(cat).items().average(); //utility method
    //this one is more complex
    4         { double sum = 0;
                for (double value : thisColumn.filter(cat).items())
                    sum += value;
                return sum;
              }
```

Comment: Is Java 8 an option? Otherwise you could use plain old reflection.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Java 8 not yet unfortunately. Plain reflection as in parsing the formula and calling the relevant members/methods via reflection?

Comment: Yes. Getting fields can take < 40 ns each for JITed code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a custom domain specific language that your users can use, and let ANTLR generate a  native parser in java that parses the expression to an executable function.

See e.g. http://arcanecoder.blogspot.be/2008/04/using-antlr-to-create-excel-like.html for an example that did something similar, or http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Expression+evaluator for a more recent one.

You can define functions like 'sum', 'average', etc. and map it to custom java code, and use e.g. $1 or ${name} to let them refer to properties.

You only define those functions that you want your user to use, so they cannot use any harmfull functions that would be available in a generic scripting language.

Comment: Which means I need to define and maintain a grammar, functions etc. I can live with the security issues linked to having access to the whole JDK and it would make my life simpler: read the code (which is Java syntax), call a compiler, run.